# how to close menu white jquery

Tags: jquery

this is my html and jquery code, how can I close this menu when click anywhere?
I use fadeout for this but not work and when open its close at time,, I want when click anywhere it close.

```
<div class="hide-recycle">
    <i class="icon-cog"> </i>
    <div class="hide-recycle-menu">
        <div class="top-triangle-hide-recycle"></div>
        <ul id="setting-hide-recycle">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/recycle.png" />حذف کردن</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/hide.png" />پنهان کردن</a></li>                                                
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".hide-recycle").hover(function(){
            $(this).css("color","rgb(90, 90, 90)");
        },function(){
            $(this).css("color","rgb(146, 146, 146)");
        });
        $(".hide-recycle").click(function(){
            $("#setting-hide-recycle").css("display","block");
            $(".top-triangle-hide-recycle").css("display","block");
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried with blur()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the menu hide code in on click of document.
Here we are using "e.stopPropagation();" to stop parent click when div is clicked .

```
$(".hide-recycle").click(function(e){
    $("#setting-hide-recycle").css("display","block");
    $(".top-triangle-hide-recycle").css("display","block");
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

For information about "e.stopPropagation();"  see the link http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

See below code .

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hide-recycle").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("color","rgb(90, 90, 90)");
    },function(){
        $(this).css("color","rgb(146, 146, 146)");
    });
    $(".hide-recycle").click(function(e){
        $("#setting-hide-recycle").css("display","block");
        $(".top-triangle-hide-recycle").css("display","block");
        e.stopPropagation();      
    });     
    $(document).on("click",function(){
        // your close code
        //alert("your close code");
        $("#setting-hide-recycle").hide();
        $(".top-triangle-hide-recycle").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide-recycle">
    <i class="icon-cog"> </i>
    <div class="hide-recycle-menu">
        <div class="top-triangle-hide-recycle"></div>
        <ul id="setting-hide-recycle">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/recycle.png" />حذف کردن</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/hide.png" />پنهان کردن</a></li>                                                
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you write e.stopPropagation(); in $(".hide-recycle").click